# Why is "application/octet-stream" not called "application/byte-stream"?

Tags: mime-types, terminology

Does anyone know why the french word for byte was used on `application/octet-stream`?
Maybe there is an historical reason, or maybe this is not the french word per se but a word from another language which is synonym.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Octet is a computer science term : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octet_(computing)

A byte is not always 8 bits(nowadays it usually is, but historically that wasn't the case). An octet is unambiguously 8 bits. So in a context like this relating to networking, where you could have devices with different definitions of a byte communicating, octet is used to remove ambiguity.